# Pygame Vector2.reflect not working when i pass an argument

Tags: python, vector, pygame

For my project using py game i have to get the reverse direction between two objects so I created  a vector to do this then I run the following line of code.

```
v2 = pygame.math.Vector2.reflect(pygame.math.Vector2.normalize(self.lastHitDirection))
```

But when this is run the following error is raised.

```
TypeError: Vector2.reflect() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

Why is this so?

Comment: Is the issue solved?

Answer (score 0):

`relfelct` is a method. See [`pygame.math.Vector2.reflect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/math.html#pygame.math.Vector2.reflect):

> returns a vector reflected of a given normal.
>
> ```
> reflect(Vector2) -> Vector2
> ```

Either

```py
reflection_vecor = incident_vector.reflect(normal_vector)
```

or

```py
reflection_vecor = pygame.math.Vector2.reflect(incident_vector, normal_vector)
```

[image]

Comment: What does v mean in this context?

Comment: @ ThePickle it is the vector2 object, you want to reflect.